# Error with Visual Studio, connect server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I got this message in Visual Studio 2010, SQL server 2008

> *A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or is not accessible. Verify the name instance is correct and that the SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider:Shared Memory Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server*

I know the solve is to enable the port number 1433 from SQL configuration tool, but when I open this tool I didn't find any item it is empty.

- System: windows8, 64bit
- Visual Studio 2010 professional

So what can I do ?

Comment: Well, for starters: **show us** the connection string you're using!

Comment: That message is the equivalent of "Something went wrong talking to Sql Server".........so we need more details.  In a car metaphor, the above is like saying "My car is making a noise.....what do you think it is?".......not being a smart butt, just saying.........

Comment: which details you need I can tell you every thing. if you can log in to my computer to see the problem, so you are welcome.
sorry, but I'm not professional i still student in IT subject and i'm an arabic. my email address: sweetsun13@live.com

Comment: "Well, for starters: show us the connection string you're using! – marc_s" Do you mean internet connection?